# In Dynamics CRM, How can I update the CreatedOn date?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Has anyone had success updating the CreatedOn field in CRM?  How can I do this?  I've seen a few vague posts saying to use a pre-sync operation, but it'd be helpful to have more information than that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Comment: I am all set. Thank you Arun! I am going to try re-uploading the records and using the "overridecreatedon" field to solve my issue.

Comment: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/212106/unable-to-update-createdon-field/559536  `The createdon field cannot be updated ever and the overridencreatedon can only be used during record creation`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's little tricky.

`CreatedOn` is system generated field, if you want to preserve the value from some legacy system, then pass the legacy value in `overriddencreatedon` field. CRM knows you want to put this `overriddencreatedon` field value in system generated `CreatedOn` field instead.

This has to be done before DB transaction, and only platform can do that. You can do this with code solution: **Pre-operation plugin** or no-code solution using CRM import.

[PRESERVE OR OVVERRIDE CREATEDON, CREATEDBY, MODIFIEDON, MODIFIEDBY FIELDS](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/learncrminfingertips/posts/preserve-or-ovverride-createdon-createdby-modifiedon-modifiedby-fields)

[Refer Byron Community Answer](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/220815/change-the-created-on-date/948025)

If data is already in CRM, then you have to copy/re-import the new data, at the same time deactivating the old records. You cannot simply update this field in client side (javascript).

Comment: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/212106/unable-to-update-createdon-field/559536  `The createdon field cannot be updated ever and the overridencreatedon can only be used during record creation`